# jQuery script works in Firefox, stops in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

A script should post a comment and when load the answer from a server. It works in Firefox, but in Chrome I guess no event is triggered, you can click a button but nothing will happen. I've checked in Chrome developer tools for some errors, but haven't found any.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="posted_comments" id="comments'.$post_id.'"></div>
<form method="post" id="c'.$post_id.'">
    <input class="comment_input" placeholder="Write your comment here..." name="comment" />
    <input name="post_id" id="post_id" hidden="hidden" value='.$post_id.' >
    <button class="comment_button" onclick="post_comment('.$post_id.')">Send</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery script:**

```
 function post_comment(id) {
     x = "#c" + id;
     y = "#comments" + id;
     $(x).submit(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'post_comment.php',
             data: $(x).serialize(),
             cache: false,

             success: function (data) {
                 $(y).html(data);
             },

             complete: function () {
                 $(x)[0].reset();
                 $(x).unbind();
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 };
```

Comment: You should consider providing us with a http://www.jsfiddle.net with your relevant code. It'll be much easier to help you.

Comment: help me with fiddle .. if you could

Comment: tip: you should use descriptive variable names, not `x` or `y`

Comment: try removing the `;` at the end, this shouldnt be here

Comment: @TecHunter - The `;` at the end would not be a problem in any browser. It's just an extra empty statement, perfectly legal albeit unnecessary.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I know that's why it's in a comment :) in an object an extra comma like `{a:"",b:"",}` works on FF and Chrome but mess with IE

Comment: any reason why you bind and unbind the submit event on each button click?

Comment: You forgot to autoclose the last `<input />` btw

Comment: @TecHunter - unless OP is using XHTML (which is hopefully not the case - no one should use that without a good reason) there is no need to use the `/>` closing on any tag. In HTML, tags like `<input>` and `<br>` are valid without the `/>`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary good to know, although jsfiddle need  `<input />`. any idea why he has `id="comments'.$post_id.'"`? it should be `id="comments.$post_id."` if we look at the concatenation and his selectors

Answer (score 2):

Don't just look in the developer tools for errors. Use the Chrome debugger to set breakpoints in your code and see which ones it gets to.

You can either add a `debugger;` statement to your code where you want to stop, or open the code in the Chrome debugger's Sources tab and click in the left margin to set a breakpoint.

Either way, set breakpoints at the beginning of the `post_comment()` function, at the beginning of the `submit()` callback (i.e. the `$.ajax()` line), and at the beginning of each of the `success` and `complete` callbacks.

Then you can see how far the code is getting, look at variables and such. This should give you some more clues.

Here's an [introduction to JavaScript debugging](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and [more information about the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Chrome submits the form without executing your function so you need to prevent the default action.

```
<button class="comment_button" data-id="' . $post_id . '">Send</button>

$('.comment_button').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   //put you ajax here, and get the post ID with $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Comment: The submit function is already returning `false` which does a `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`. Also note that if you handle the `click` event on the button you will fail to intercept the submit if the Enter key is used in an input field in the form. You should handle the `submit` event on the form instead, which the original code does.

Comment: The ``return false;`` in the original snippet is nested in a function passed to submit. The actual event callback (``post_comment``) doesn't return false.

OP should move ``return false`` at the end of ``post_comment``

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<php include ('data.php');?>
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name here"/><br>
    <label>Comment:</label>
    <textarea name="comment" type="text" placeholder="Write a comment here"/></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

then create a action file

action.php

```
<?php 
$handle = fopen("data.php", "a");
if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) &&  strlen( $_POST['name'] ))
    {
fwrite($handle,"<br>");
fwrite($handle,'---------------------------------------');
fwrite($handle,"<br><b>");
fwrite($handle,$_POST["name"]);
fwrite($handle,'<br> Comment: <br>');
fwrite($handle,$_POST["comment"]);
fclose($handle); 
header("Location: ./index.php");
       }
else
     {
echo "name required <br> <a href='./index.php'>OK</a>";
      }
exit;
?>
```

You need to edit some code if its not works

Answer (score 0):

According to :

```
<div class="posted_comments" id="comments'.$post_id.'"></div>
<form method="post" id="c'.$post_id.'">
```

And:

```
x = "#c" + id;
y = "#comments" + id;
```

if you call it like :

```
post_comment('.$post_id.')
```

Then your variables would be :

```
x = "#c.$post_id.";
y = "#comments.$post_id.";
```

In this case your ID are wrong, you have extra single quotes.